# How to know if a new tag is created in django-tagging?

Tags: django-tagging

How can I know if a new tag is created for a model? Looks like the django-tagging API does not provide such method. I'm new to both Django and django-tagging app and would like to hear your advice.

**Update:** what I'm trying to acomplish is to add more properties to tags. I think to have another model TagProperties linked to Tag model. And every time the Tag is save I save the TagProperies as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use django [signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/signals/).  You could connect a [`post_save`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal to the `Tag` model and handle that for when a new instance is created.

Comment: ars, thanks for the answer. I'll try that out. BTW, I have updated the question and you may see another solution.

Comment: This should be fine: you can save your TagProperties object in the `post_save` handler.